# How to create labels and text boxes dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic, textbox

Im suppose to create text boxes dynamically for x amount of courses that the user inputs. Each course, the user has to put "Course Title, and Mark Recieved". So lets say the user is taking 3 courses this semester. I need to make it so that theres 6 text boxes with the title of Course Title, and Mark Recieved for every two text box. Im not sure how to do this

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="textbox">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" onclick="addFunction()" value="Add"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
function addFunction() {
        var table = document.getElementById("textbox");
        var rowlen = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowlen);
        row.id=rowlen;
        var arr = [ 'textboxfiledname' ]
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var x = row.insertCell(i)
            if (i == 1) {
                x.innerHTML = "<input type='button' onclick='removeCell(" + row.id+ ")' value=Delete>"
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "<label>"+arr[i]+"</label><input type='textbox' name='"+arr[i]+"'>"
            }
        }
    }
    function removeCell(rowid) {
        var table = document.getElementById(rowid).remove();
    }
</script>
```